# How to get alignment between sentiment module and constituency parser in CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm using Stanford coreNLP to both parse a text and get sentiment information. The two models give two `Tree` objects, but they are not related. Is there an easy way to navigate the two elements at the same time, so having an alignment between the two at a token level?

Comment: Why do you say that the two trees "are not related?" The constituency parse and the sentiment-labeled parse should look the same, I think (apart from presence / lack of sentiment annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the sentiment tree as a model of both the grammatical parse and the sentiment — it's simply the original parse tree with extra annotations.

*Explanation:* If you're using the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline, the sentiment annotator draws directly from the parse annotator to build its tree. The tree provided by the sentiment annotator is then just the same binarized parse tree with extra sentiment annotations.